# cucumber-js: access worldParameters

Tags: cucumber, cucumberjs

I have a cucumber-js and playwright project.

I want to access worldParameters key and value which is defined in cucumber.js file as follows:

```
worldParameters: {
  baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com'
}
```

How can I access baseUrl and use it in my steps.js file?

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/docs/configuration.md), the config file should have a format as below.

```
module.exports = {
 default: {
  worldParameters: {
  appUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  },
 }
}
```

Then as per tests [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/features/world_parameters.feature), you should be able to access the parameters by using `this.parameters.appUrl` in your code.

Comment: That's great. I have tried it to assign this.parameters.appUrl to a variable, however I was getting undefined, is there any way I can assign it to appUrl, in before hooks?

Comment: this.parameters.appUrl  -  value should be read from inside cucumber annotations (like Given, When..etc,).  It will throw undefined error message if you read value from outside / custom functions instead of reading from cucumber annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Define a file named 'cucumber.js' in your root directory and define your code like below:

```
    let worldOptions = {
  browserName: browser,
  environment: env,
  partition: partition,
  project: project,
  timestamp: global.timestamp,
  reportDir: global.reportDir,
  headless: headless,
  slowMotion: slowMotion,
  partition: partition,
  target: target,
  browserVersion: browserVersion,
  os: os,
  osVersion: osVersion,
  device: device
};
console.log('cucumber js world options: ' + JSON.stringify(worldOptions));


let common = [
  '--require ./support/', // Load hooks
  './**/tests/features/', // Specify our feature files
  '--require-module ts-node/register', // Load TypeScript module
  '--require ./**/tests/steps/**/', // Load step definitions
  '-f @cucumber/pretty-formatter',
  // '--format json:reports/' + project + '/'+global.timestamp +'/cucumber_report.json',
  '--format json:' + global.reportDir + 'cucumber_report.json',
  '--parallel ' + (parallel !== undefined ? parallel : 1) + ' --world-parameters ' + JSON.stringify(worldOptions),
  '--publish-quiet'
].join(' ');
```

Now, cucumber 'this' object holds your world params data and read them usin 'this.World.browserName'